# wget + how to know list of kit under folder

Tags: linux, wget, curl

we can download the kit `HDP-2.6.3.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz`

by the follwing wget

```
wget http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/HDP-2.6.3.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz

--2018-01-14 17:16:18--  http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0/HDP-2.6.3.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz
Resolving public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)... 13.32.145.17, 13.32.145.111, 13.32.145.237, ...
Connecting to public-repo-1.hortonworks.com (public-repo-1.hortonworks.com)|13.32.145.17|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 7072846515 (6.6G) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘HDP-2.6.3.0-centos6-rpm.tar.gz.1’

 0% [                                                                                                                                       ] 4,627,213    114KB/s  eta 5h
```

but how to know what are the list of the kits under -  `http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos6/2.x/updates/2.6.3.0`

by `wget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the web server doesn't return a list of files, wget can't show you either.

Comment: This may well be the answer to the question.